# Are multiple atomic directives treated as a single critical section with OpenMP?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, atomic, critical-section

I have this code from my professor:

```
   pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count)
   {
      int i;
      double my_sum = 0.0;
      for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      #pragma omp atomic
         my_sum += sin(i);
      }
   }
```

I need to determine if the n atomic directives are treated as a single critical section. It seems to me that the question doesn't even make sense because my_sum is a variable local to each thread, so I wanted to start by asking here.

Comment: Indeed, any kind of synchronisation, including atomics, makes no sense with private variables. That said, unlike critical sections, atomics are not locks. They are implemented using CPU instructions whose execution is uninterruptible, i.e., they either execute as a whole or not at all.

Comment: Thank you. When an atomic operation executes, no other thread is allowed to modify the variable that the atomic operation is operating on, correct? So its functioning like a critical section without all the overhead incurred from locking/unlocking?

Comment: @ConnorWilliams yes, it is like that